# How to solve quadratic equations with Newton-Raphson's method in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Maybe I just don't understand maths. I tried different formulas but roots are really far away from correct ones. 
You are given only 3 coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = float(input())
b = float(input())
c = float(input())
x1 = -b / 2 * a + 0.0000001
x2 = -b / 2 * a - 0.0000001
for i in range(10000):
    x1 = x1 - (a * x1**2 + b * x1 + c) / (2 * a * x1 + b)
    x2 = x2 - (a * x2**2 + b * x2 + c) / (2 * a * x2 + b)
print(x1, x2)
```

You can try this one. Try changing the constants to change accuracy.